# using tuples to add values to dictionary keys

Tags: dictionary, tuples, python-3.9

I made the code

```
population = {
    'Shanghai': 17.8,
    'Istanbul': 13.3,
    'Karachi': 13.0,
    'Mumbai': 12.5
    }
bob, chase, exacu = 32, 42, 53
ha = bob, chase, exacu
population['bob', 'chase', 'exacu'] = ha
print(population)
```

I received the output

```
{'Shanghai': 17.8, 'Istanbul': 13.3, 'Karachi': 13.0, 'Mumbai': 12.5, ('bob', 'chase', 'exacu'): (32, 42, 53)}
```

I expected the output

```
{'Shanghai': 17.8, 'Istanbul': 13.3, 'Karachi': 13.0, 'Mumbai': 12.5, 'bob': 32, 'chase': 42, 'exacu': 53}
```

can someone explain how to receive the expected output? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant assign to multiple keys like that, that will just make one key which consist of tuples.

```
population = {
    'Shanghai': 17.8,
    'Istanbul': 13.3,
    'Karachi': 13.0,
    'Mumbai': 12.5
    }
bob, chase, exacu = 32, 42, 53
ha = bob, chase, exacu

keys = 'bob', 'chase', 'exacu'
for x,y in zip(keys,ha):
    population[x] = y

print(population)

>>> {'Shanghai': 17.8, 'Istanbul': 13.3, 'Karachi': 13.0, 'Mumbai': 12.5, 'bob': 32, 'chase': 42, 'exacu': 53}
```